# Broken Pipeline in Tomcat

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, broken-pipe

We are running around 50 apps on **Tomcat/7.0.57**, all are client API accessible via SOAP call. The problem we are facing is that we are getting broken pipeline error (**ClientAbortException**). Now I assume I cannot avoid this issue completely, the problem I am facing is the server is not recovering from this issue. It starts giving the error in a series. I need to restart the service/server to rectify the issue, that is not a very good idea for live servers.

**Tomcat is running with these parameters:**

```
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/apachetomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms3072m -Xmx3072m -XX:NewSize=1024m -XX:MaxNewSize=1024m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/apachetomcat/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/apachetomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/apachetomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/apachetomcat -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/apachetomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/share/apachetomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

**And the error log is as follows:**

```
[ERROR] java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:78)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.sendUsingOutputStream(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:364)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:241)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.sendFault(AxisEngine.java:526)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.handleFault(AxisServlet.java:433)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.processAxisFault(AxisServlet.java:398)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:188)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1692)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.close(BaseStreamWriter.java:288)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamWriterWrapper.close(XMLStreamWriterWrapper.java:46)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.close(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:222)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:192)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:407)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:420)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:91)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:96)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:214)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.close(BufferingXmlWriter.java:194)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1690)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:366)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:240)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:117)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:192)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:499)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:402)
        ... 42 more
[INFO] org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
```

Please let me know if anyone needs any more information to help me rectify this.

Comment: So after getting one "ClientAbortException" all subsequent requests fail with the same thing? We used to get those exceptions quite a lot where I last worked (because clients would genuinely hang up), but it never caused all subsequent requests to fail...

Comment: This exception cause a request long time to process, which will make other subsequent requests to be in queue, then they will take more time to process and execute, Later at one point, all request takes more time to process, which hang up the service and further on there are only "Brokeb Pipe" error exception in the logs.